# Extract table data from interactive webpage with python

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to get the table data from a certain website to play with the data statistically, however I'm failing on the interactive button which selects each sector from the linked race. How can I iterate through the button list and store each table in a list or a resulting df? An explanation would be appreciated so I can learn how this works. So far I can only extract the text from the first page:

```
site = "http://live.fis-ski.com/cc-4023/results-pda.htm" 

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options= options)
driver.get(site)

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tab1'))   
        )
    print(main.text)
    result = main.text
except:
     driver.quit()
```

This gives me just a list of the main page with each sector.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You only need to click the "MORE" button and extract the `tab2` element content or something more?

Comment: I want the split times not the weather data. When running the above code, despite changing the section button I always get the same text output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Select` you can select the value of the dropdown and change the race type. With `.get_attribute('innerText')` you can get the values of the hidden rows too (`.text` doesn't work for them). With `pandas` you can store data in a dataframe, eventually saving it to csv.

```
dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'int1')))
races = dropdown.text.replace('Auto follow\n','').strip().split('\n')
data = dict.fromkeys(races)

for race in races:
    print(race)
    Select(dropdown).select_by_visible_text(race)
    time.sleep(1)
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='resultpoint1']/ul/li")
    table = []
    
    for row in rows:
        columns = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./div")
        # values = [c.get_attribute('innerText') for c in columns] <-- very slow
        values = driver.execute_script("var result = [];" +
        "var all = arguments[0];" +
        "for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {" +
        "    result.push(all[i].innerText);" +
        "} " +
        " return result;", columns)
        table.append(values)

    columns_class = [c.get_attribute('class').split()[0].replace('_order','_rank') for c in columns]
    column_names = [driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#result-1 .tableheader .'+ c).text for c in columns_class]
    data[race] = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=column_names)
    data[race].to_csv(race+'.csv', index=False)
```

Each table is saved in a dict, for example `data['2500 m']` prints the following

[image]

Comment: My code is breaking at some point giving this error : ValueError: 0 columns passed, passed data had 7 columns. I tried to fix it by using this column_names = [c.text for c in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#result1 .tableheader div:not([class*=hidden])')][:num_columns]. which doesn't change the error. Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Hansson They changed the site layout so I had to adapt the code a bit, try the new one and let me know. Notice that I replaced `[c.get_attribute('innerText') for c in columns]` with a javascript code (`driver.execute_script(...)`) because javascript it's faster. In fact with the old code the loop `for row in rows` took 6 seconds, while with javascript only 1 second

Comment: Working again now, thanks a lot. Can you give me a hint to where I can improve my knowledge in this field? What did you do to learn this?

Comment: @Hansson For me this is just a hobby, I have been learning selenium slowly for the last few years by automating different tasks (browser games, download of files, scrape data from forums, etc.). During the process I always face some problems, but luckily on internet there are many sites that help us, and if I don't find a solution I ask here. So I suggest you to try automating several tasks, start with simple ones to become familiar with the basic functions, and keep track in a file of the important things, for example my file is https://pastebin.com/PjgFviRC

Comment: @Hansson Also, I suggest you using BeautifulSoup which is faster than selenium and helpful to become familiar with css selectors and xpath, you can also use them together for the same task