# How can I scroll a pop up element from Abnb with Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, popup

hey guys I'm scrapping abnb with Selenium-Python. The issue is that I want to scrap the reviews from each abnb but in order to scrap them I need to scroll down the pop up element that appears.

As you can see on the image I click the button then the pop-up element appears and then I want to scroll but I can't. Of course as you can see all the reviews don't appear and I have to scroll if I want them to appear, they also don't appear on the DevTools from google chrome unless I scroll.

[image]

I tried:

```
reviews_lista = []
boton_revs = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-testid='pdp-show-all-reviews-button']")
boton_revs.click()
```

I clicked on the button that you see on the image.

I selected the whole POP UP

```
bloque_pop = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_14vzertx']")
```

I tried to scroll with this code but it didn't work

```
scroll = 0
while scroll < 5: # scroll 5 times
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', bloque_pop)
    time.sleep(1)
    scroll += 1
```

I also tried

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
```

and this too:

```
bloque_pop = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_14vzertx']")
for i in range(5):
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", bloque_pop)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)", bloque_pop)
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to scroll inside a popup is to scrape elements contained in the popup and then scroll to the last element by using the javascript command `scrollIntoView`.

```
popup_reviews = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role=dialog] div[data-review-id]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', popup_reviews[-1])
```

Comment: So I have to execute those and that's that. I already had a similar code on the question but somehow it didn't work, after reading your answer I udnerstood and tried also with my code and it worked. Seems like after all I don't know Selenium at all. Can you tell me how it works and where did you get documented for Selenium in general?

Thnk u a lot btw you saved me!

Comment: But while applying a WHILE bocule it takes too long, why would it be?

Comment: @Elmauro This is the official documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ I suggest you start from here and test your skill with little projects

Comment: @Elmauro Show me the code of the while loop so that i can understand why it is slow

Comment: Nah man I'm retarded I didnt put a n+=1 in the While func and it looped forever. And for the code I had that supposedly worked... it didnt lol. 
Tahnks man u saved me. BTW I thought scraping the AIRBNB webpage was already a "hard" project, it isn't?

Comment: @Elmauro Well it depends by the definition of "hard" :) by the way, I suggest you starting scraping forums (for example, take a thread and scrape each message with text, username, date, likes (if any), etc) and tables. Also, I suggest you reading all my answers, some of them contain the full code to scrape something, for example: [google jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75486908/8157304), [table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75458440/8157304), [another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75449204/8157304), [eshop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75447998/8157304)...

Comment: @Elmauro ... [tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75389315/8157304), [pinterest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75386796/8157304), [bandcamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75334642/8157304), [another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75324886/8157304). Moreover, when you find a useful function or snippet code, I suggest you writing it in a file so that you can easily recall it when necessary. For example this is my simple txt file https://pastebin.com/PjgFviRC